# States Drop Down Missing (Magento)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am currently running Magento version 1.7.0.2. States are not available in the Default State dropdown in admin area. I have only option to choose asterisk (*) with no States listed. I have selected United State as Origin country. Under Shipping Settings in Origin section Region/State field is replaced with text area where it should have a dropdown with options to select States. I have tried all possible options and setting but nothing seems to be working. I even posted the question on Magento forum but there was no one to look into the issue. I have attached a Screenshot of the same below. I need to fix this as soon as possible. Any help will be valued and highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you table in the magento database is missing the states... look at the magento mySQL Table "directory_country_region" and see if your states are there

Comment: @Jeff u were right. When I select "directory_country_region" table I can view only Structure not the Browse option. IS there any way to fix the issue? Thanks

Comment: you can import the state list to that table. it is part of the magento default table so you should be able to get it from somewhere. Or i can export mine and get it to you somehow

Comment: @Jeff I imported the table from one of my Magento installation which fixed the issue. Thanks a lot for the help. How do I mark your comment as correct resolution?

Comment: I just added to the answer post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you table in the magento database is missing the states... look at the magento mySQL Table "directory_country_region" and see if your states are there

(See Comments)